# New-PSSession : Relative URIs are not supported in the creation of > remote sessions

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I found this useful script for uploading photos on Exchange Server: 
:

first error:

> New-PSSession : Relative URIs are not supported in the creation of
>   remote sessions. At line:110 char:15
>   +             $session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri ...
>   +
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MAIL-PERO.appl.campari.priv:Uri) [New-PSSession],
>   NotSupportedException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSSessionCommand

second error:

> The term 'get-mailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

[Powersheel GUI](http://mikepfeiffer.net/2010/05/manage-exchange-2010-thumbnail-photos-with-a-powershell-based-gui/)

Answer (score 0):

The script is meant for exchange2010, so make sure you have it, not anything newer, not anything lower. Otherwise you have to update the script. It's hardcoded to use 2010 libraries.

Also, as the error said, don't use relative URLs.

For urls, use `https://yourexchangeUri.com`